# Upgrading existing ICU on CentOS6.9

Tags: php, centos6, pecl, icu, intl

All a total newbie here and not a developer. However a PHP script I wish to install which uses Yii framework requires a higher version of ICU than the default 4.2.1 on CentOS 6.

So some background -

a) I am on IBM Baremetal servers and Softlayer support sucks
b) They have me on CentOS 6.9
c) PHP 5, 6 7 are all running
d) PHP Pear is installed
e) I installed Intl extension via EasyApache on cPanel/WHM across 3 flavors of PHP that are running
f) Then the script said I needed ICU 49 or higher (they have renamed versions to two digit combos now the latest is 59)

I looked up these two links

http://lty.in/GuuqfN

http://lty.in/yM8ptm

Using the first link which I followed step by step I have reached the step where pecl needs to be invoked However on the sever there is no pecl - despite php-pear being active as an extension

I am stuck here "pecl install intl"

I cant seem to figure out how to get pecl installed over php-pear or if that is even required...under bin there is no sub-directory pecl

Also two more points -

a) Should I uninstall easyapache based intl first?
b) Please note by defauly ICU 4.2.1 a very old version exits

Please help and provide simple and clear steps for a newbie to upgrade ICU to latest version from icu project site if required.

Thank you kindly in advance!

Answer (score 1):

locate pecl was utilized to find pecl - apparently pecl is inconsistently placed on install of php-pear i.e. not under root/bin/pecl was placed in a deeper sub-dir path.

Then execution of pecl install intl command hands when using cPanel interface. Shell command execution completed successfully.

Thanks everyone - hope this helps others out